# Find the largest number backbone collection?

Tags: backbone.js

```
playersCollection.each(function(player) {
    // how do I determine the model with the largest attribute
    player.get('points') // this is the attribute
    //Not sure what to write to filter through all the models with this attribute 
    //Then return the object that is the largest?
});
```

Let's say there are three models, each have a points attribute 6,10,21 how do I filter through them and return the one with 21 (largest number in the collection).

Simple but I am not sure which method to use, and how to use in this context http://backbonejs.org/

Should be simple for most?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore's `max` method is the solution.

Since Backbone Collection merged some Underscore methods including `max`, you can use it on Collection instance directly.

```
playersCollection.max(function(player){
  return player.get('points');
});

// => {name: 'Joe', points: 21};
```

See the demo here: http://jsbin.com/ACAcALak/2/edit?html,js,console

Ref:

1. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods
2. http://underscorejs.org/#max

Comment: I think it should be `player.get('points');` or `player.attributes.points`.

Comment: Thanks I saw a post saying to use the `max` method I couldn't get it to work, it had some extra code based on the person that asked that question and threw me off, this helps, and thanks for the fiddle always a great learning tool!